# How to test the type contained in a map

Tags: c++, templates

Say I had a template function that calculates the sum of a map's elements like this:

```
template <class A, class B> double Total(const map<A, B>& cntr)
{
    map<A, B>::const_iterator iter;
    double total = 0;

    for (iter = cntr.begin(); iter != cntr.end(); ++iter)
        total += iter->second;

    return total;
}
```

It would work fine whenever B was a numeric type; however, obviously if you passed in a reference to something like `map<int, string>`, it wouldn't work.

I was wondering how I could test the type contained in the non-key section of the map so I can through an exception or something. I tried using isdigit() but couldn't seem to get a working version.

EDIT: My intended use of the test would be to add functionality so that the int type is always used to calculate the total, so I can pass in `map<int, string>` or `map<string, int>` and it will always calculate the int types.

Comment: I'm sure the compiler will tell you that `+=` doesn't work for double and string.

Comment: Why is your return type `double` and not `B`?

Comment: Sorry, poorly phrased. I didn't specify my intended use. Edited.

Comment: In the declaration, `typename` is missing. It should be `typename map<A, B>::const_iterator`

Comment: I'm smelling an XY problem here. What are you *actually* trying to accomplish, big-picture style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use type traits in C++11 or boost.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class A, class B> double Sum(const map<A, B>& cntr)
{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<B>::value, "Invalid type!");
    map<A, B>::const_iterator iter;
    double total = 0;

    for (iter = cntr.begin(); iter != cntr.end(); ++iter)
        total += iter->second;

    return total;
}
```

Keep in mind that types that are invalid will simply not compile, even without the assertion.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is too restrictive, since `map` takes more than two template arguments, and you also might like to support other types like `unordered_map`. I suggest a template like this:

```
template <typename Map>
typename Map::mapped_type accumulate(Map const & m)
{
    typedef typename Map::mapped_type type;
    type result;

    // if you like:
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<type>::value, "Mapped type cannot be accumulated over.");

    for (auto it = m.cbegin(), end = m.cend(); it != end; ++it) // or your favourte loop construct
    {
        result += it->second;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Actually you *can* accumulate over strings, too, by concatenation, but I've added the static assertion check for arithmetic types in case you want to restrict to that. Alternatively, if you want to convert strings to numbers, you could write a more general "add" wrapper that uses `std::stoul` or `std::stod` on strings.

A non-zero starting value could also be provided easily.

Alternatively yet, the whole thing could be expressed as a one-liner using `std::accumulate` and a lambda:

```
auto result = std::accumulate(m.cbegin(), m.cend(), 0.0,
  [](double d, Map::value_type const & p) -> double { return d + p.second; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well in fact your code will not compile if you try to call your code with arguments of types such that the opertor +=(double a, const B& o) is undefined so you are safe in the case you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may try to use `static_cast` operator to detect if an argument can be casted to a number type. For example, a function

```
template <class T> void func (T arg) {
  double u = static_cast<double> (arg);
  //do foo
}
```

If `arg` is not of a number type, compiler must perform compile time error.